# How I can call json method to bool class?

Tags: c#, json-rpc

I want to call a method from class JsonRpc:

```
public void makeRequest<T>(JsonRequest jsonRpc, IObserver<JsonResponse<T>> obs)
```

in another test case class:

```
public class Experiment{
public bool Test()
{
    logger.Write("JSON rpc request ");
    JsonRpcClient jsrpc = new JsonRpcClient();
    jsrpc.sendAndReceive(messageToSend);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //var js = JsonRequest.jsonRpc; 
    //var obs = IObserver.
    jsrpc.makeRequest();
}
}
```

I get error message : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter.

This class is a test case which runs its.

Summarize: I want to get json request/response from Network>WS, method Project_get.

Regards,
Bartt